# Unable to run JEST test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm facing an issue when I try to import something using require() function in jest test file.

**script2.test.js**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

it('test function', () => {
  expect(4).toEqual(4);
});
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "jest-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.15.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "jest": "^27.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

**babel.config.cjs**

```
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}
```

I'm getting following errors when I run the test using npm test

```
FAIL  ./script2.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax. 

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.


    Details:
    
        C:\work\jest-udemy\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js:9
        import http from 'http';
        ^^^^^^
    
        SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    
        > 1 | const fetch = require('node-fetch');
        |                   ^
```

I'm new to JEST, any help is much appreciated.
My Node version is 14.17.3
Thanks you.

Comment: Have you tried `import fetch from 'node-fetch';` instead of `require`? You have `type: "module` in your package.json

Comment: @tromgy Yes, it still show me this error, 
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one still needs to jump through the hoops to make jest work with ESM.

In **package.json** change your script to:

```
"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
```

And in **script2.test.js** use `import`:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

P.S. This was tested with node 14.15.1

Comment: @tromy This worked for me.! Appreciate. Thank you.